# Can Azure Blob Storage synchronize to a source control repo?

Tags: git, azure, mercurial, azure-blob-storage

I have a web site for which the content is stored as a collection of photographs in JPEG files, along with some manually edited XML files containing metadata.  It's currently hosted with an old-school web hosting company, and I'm to migrate to Microsoft Azure in the near future.

Right now, I manually update files through FTP, and I'm like to try to improve the workflow so that it' less tedious and error-prone.  Ideally, I'd like to configure an Azure Blob Storage account so that it mirrors a version control repo (preferably Mercurial, although I could live with migrating to Git if I really had to).  I'd like to have a configuration where, when I push to the repo, it detects which files have changed and updates those files in the storage account.  Does Azure support doing this, or would I have to write my own scripts if I wanted it?

Answer (score 1):

Azure Storage has no mechanism to do comparisons with an external set of resources. You'd need to do this on your own. To assist you, each blob does have a timestamp and an ETag (which gets updated when the blob is updated).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have too many files, you can try to leverage the [Custom Deployment Script](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Custom-Deployment-Script) to create your custom script in PHP, Node.js, python or C# and implement with Azure Storage SDKs for your requirement.

Otherwise, you can leverage [Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer](http://storageexplorer.com/) to upload your files to Azure Storage from local with a ease.

Furthermore, we suggest you to do some modifications about your application's architecture. Please use Azure Storage to store your image files, do not store your images files on Azure Web Apps with your application. When you have several instances of your Azure Web Apps, and the files which will be effected by user operations may get out of synchronization.